# Rails: How should I run my associated objects' callbacks before the parent's callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, callback, activemodel

I have an `Invoice` model, which `has_many :line_items`.

Both models have `before_validation` callbacks. The invoice's callback requires that the line items' callbacks have been run first. However, by default the invoice's callback gets run, then the callback for each line item is run.

Is there a good way ensure that the line items are validated first, then the invoice?

At the moment, I'm toying with something like this:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :do_something
  ...

private
  def do_something
    line_items.each { |line_item| line_item.run_callbacks(:validation) }
    # Then do whatever I need here - I've forced the callback order
  end
end
```

Is there a nicer way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if they are valid

```
def do_something
  line_items.all?(&:valid?)
  # Then do whatever I need here - I've forced the callback order
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's better. Always good to see Ruby niceties you don't know about!